# Eeeek! Gigantic Gravatar nearly gave me a heart attack on the spot - what gives?

Tags: bug, gravatar, chat-ads

I was visiting [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166972/automatic-ban-concerns) and stumbled across this:

[image]

I almost fell off of my chair! (Penguins aren't noted for their ability to remain seated on a chair for long periods of time. They also have really weak hearts.) The Gravatar is nearly 5.5 times the size of the others.

The URL of the image reveals the problem:

> http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/!https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljxup.png?g=1&s=128?s=23&d=identicon&r=PG

The `s` parameter is set to `128` which will return a 128x128 Gravatar. The other images are set to `23`.

Does it have anything to do with [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture/)?

Comment: Well, Manishearth is a *great* guy